# How to get the value of a dictionary declared inside a class as a local variable with Python

Tags: python, list, class, function, dictionary

I am wondering how can I get the value of a dictionary declared as local variable inside a class? look at my source below. 
Note: If I declare this variable inside the function get_current_weather it just works fine

```
class Weather(object):
    weather = {
        'January' : 'cold',
        'Febrary' : 'cold'
        }

    def get_current_weather(self):             
        print weather['January']

weather = Weather()
weather.get_current_weather()
```

Terminal error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "game.py", line 27, in <module>
weather.get_current_weather()
File "game.py", line 24, in get_current_weather
print weather['January']
**TypeError: 'Weather' object is not subscriptable**
```

Comment: P.S `weather` is not a list its a dictionary

Comment: `get_current_weather` should be indented if you want it to be a member of class Weather.

Comment: @DavidMarek thank you. It seems like Stackoverflow doesn't paste it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `self.weather`, otherwise python will try to find a global variable named `weather`:

```
def get_current_weather(self):
    print self.weather['January']  # or  Weather.weather['January']
```

A class is a namespace in itself, so variables inside class become it's attribute :

i.e `weather` inside class is actually : `Weather.weather`

Example:

```
>>> class A:
...     foo = 1
...     bar = 2
...     
>>> A.foo
1
>>> A.bar
2
```